# Static files not loading on Django deploy on digitalocean app

Tags: django, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I am trying to deploy a Django application on DigitalOcean. However, static files are not getting served on the server. I am not sure what the issue is since they work fine locally. The following is my settings file:

```py
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
from pathlib import Path

import os
import sys
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY", get_random_secret_key())


DEBUG = os.getenv("DEBUG", "False") == "True"
DEVELOPMENT_MODE = os.getenv("DEVELOPMENT_MODE", "False") == "True"

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS", "127.0.0.1,localhost").split(",")

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app.apps.AppConfig',
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",  # new
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


if DEVELOPMENT_MODE is True:
    DATABASES = {
        "default": {
            "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
            "NAME": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3"),
        }
    }
elif len(sys.argv) > 0 and sys.argv[1] != 'collectstatic':
    if os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", None) is None:
        raise Exception("DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined")
    DATABASES = {
        "default": dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")),
    }



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True



STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static"]  
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'  # new


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: Are you using a Digital Ocean droplet? Are you serving the app via nginx? or just using a development server such as `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` ?

Comment: I've just spun this up using digital ocean's app pipeline - following this article https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/

Comment: Did you do [this](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/#step-5-deploying-your-static-files) part of the article? I am guessing it has something to do with this

Comment: OMG - I totally missed this part of the article - have been going to and forth for 4 hours. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome. Glad to help. Is it okay if I add this as an answer so that you can accept it?

Comment: If you are wanting to use whitenoise rather than the DigitalOcean app, you will need to include another line in your middleware: https://whitenoise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django.html#enable-whitenoise

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments.
Following [this](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/#step-5-deploying-your-static-files) part of the article seems to fix the issue

Comment: Please accept the accept if it helped you so that it will help someone else. Thank you